# Can I include the default editor inside a webview in VSCode?

Tags: webview, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In my project I created a Webview extension for Visual Studio Code. Inside the Webview I have a text editor (currently monaco editor) and a graphical Modeler.

Now I wondered if there is any way to replace the monaco editor inside my Webview with the standard editor of Visual Studio Code. This would be extremely helpful because I would not have to worry about connecting the custom text Editor to my LSP Extensions and also have 100% the same functionalities as in the rest of Visual Studio Code.

Do You know of any way in which I could achieve this goal?

Best Regards
Thomas

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: If you want the original editing functionality of vscode then use a normal editor instead of a webview. Use the webview only for your modeler.

Answer (score 2):

The feature request you are looking forward is https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/93265

It is being implemented

In VS Code `Help > Interactive Playground` you can have an idea of what it will look like, even if it is not exposed through the API yet.

Meanwhile, [vscode-python](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python) configures the Monaco Editor to look as much as possible to the native text editor.